# Show that these interpretations describe the same set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be bijective with inverse function $f^{-1}: B \rightarrow A$, and let $B' \subset B$.

Then the symbol $f^{-1}(B')$ has two interpretations.

1. The preimage of $B'$ under $f$.
2. Image of $B'$ under $f^{-1}$.

Show that both interpretations are the same set.

From the first interpretation we get the set $f^{-1}(B')=\{x\in A \mid f(x)\in B'\}$.

From the second interpretation we get the set $f^{-1}(B')=\{f^{-1}(y) \mid y\in B'\}$.

Can we just say that these sets are equal? Or do we have to show also something?

Comment: You have to *show* that these sets are equal.

Comment: We have the following: \begin{align*}x\in f^{-1}(B')&\iff x\in A \text{ with } f(x)=:b\in B' \\ & \iff x=f^{-1}(b) \\ & \iff x\in f^{-1}(B')\end{align*} Can we take everywhere $\iff$ or dowe have to show each implication seperately? @TheSilverDoe

Comment: you should first give different names to the two sets : if you call them both $f^{-1}(B')$, we don't see the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretation 1 (The inverse image of $B'$ under $f$): Define $S_1$ in such a way
$$
\forall x\bigg(\big(x \in A \rightarrow (f(x) \in B' \equiv x \in S_1)\big) \wedge \big(x \notin A \rightarrow x \notin S_1\big)\bigg)
$$
Interpretation 2 (The image of $B'$ under $f^{-1}$): Define $S_2$ in such a way
$$
\forall x\bigg(x \in S_2 \equiv \exists y\big(y \in B' \wedge f^{-1}(y)=x\big)\bigg)
$$

Now we show that $S_1=S_2$.

On one hand, if $x \in S_1$, then $f(x) \in B'$. $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x \rightarrow x \in S_2$.

On the other hand, conversely, if $x \in S_2$, then $\exists y(y \in B' \wedge f^{-1}(y)=x)$. $f(x)=f(f^{-1}(y))=y \in B' \rightarrow x \in S_1$.

Therefore, $S_1=S_2$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: Thank you!! :-)